# Determine if the limit exists and then find its value

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 49}  {\sqrt{x}-7 \over x-49}$$

Using my properties of limits I just plugged in $49$ for $x$ and ended up with an answer of $0$. I was wondering if I did this correctly as it almost feels too simple to be correct

Comment: $0/0$ does not necessarily imply the limit is zero. Instead, I would suggest first factoring the denominator to cancel with the numerator, and then take the limit.

Comment: You can use L'Hôpital's rule and you'll easily get the result.

Comment: **0 / 0 is nonsense.**

Comment: @LorenzoComoglio L'Hopital here is circular... this *is* a derivative already, using L'Hopital to compute it is computing two derivatives to compute a derivative.

Comment: @ClementC., I get $\lim_{x \to 49}  {\sqrt{x}-7 \over x-49}=\lim_{x \to 49}  {1 \over 2\sqrt{x}}=1/14$

Comment: @LorenzoComoglio I am not saying it does not give the right answer, I am saying it is incredibly overkill and circular. The limit is exactly $f'(49)$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, by the very definition of derivative. But to apply L'Hopital, you have to differentiate $\sqrt{\cdot}$ **and** apply a non-trivial theorem on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\neq 49$ and $x>0$, $$\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-7}{x-49}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-7}{\sqrt{x}^2-7^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-7}{(\sqrt{x}-7)(\sqrt{x}+7)}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}+7}$$

So the function can be prolongated in $x=49$ and the limit is $1/(\sqrt{49}+7)=1/14$.

**Remarks on indeterminate "0/0"** $f:x\mapsto \frac{x^2}{x}$ can be made continuous in 0 (with $f(0)=0$). $f:x\mapsto \frac{x}{x^2}$ cannot be made continuous in 0. $f:x\mapsto \frac{x}{x}$ can be made continuous in 0 (with $f(0)=1$). The question is *whether the function has a limit around the point where it is not defined*.

Answer (score 2):

An indeterminate form "$0/0$" does not mean the limit does not exist. It can exist (think of for instance $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ when $x\to 0$), can fail to exist (e.g., $\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{x^2}$ when $x\to 0$) -- everything is possible, so you need to dig deeper to find the answer.

**Hint:** can you recognize a derivative i.e. something of the form 
$$
f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
$$
for some function $f$ differentiable at $a$ (here, $a=49$)?

Comment: So would instead the answer be 1/7?

Comment: Not quite, it'll be $1/14$. How did you arrive to $1/7$?

Comment: I am sorry could you explain to me how you got to 1/14, did you use the derivative formula or something else. I am very new to calculus so I do not know many of the laws or rules yet.

Comment: Consider $f$ defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, Then $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, and you are looking for $f'(49)$. @user344249

Comment: So will f^' (x) when x= the square root of x always be 1/2 square root of x?

Comment: Yes, this is the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$. More generally (these are good to know), we have $\frac{d}{dx} x^a = a x^{a-1}$, for any fixed $a$ (the square root is just the case where $a=\frac{1}{2}$). You may want to have a look e.g. at [this list of common derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rules_of_computation).

Comment: Okay thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Rationalizing the numerator is the usual method for this, and someone's already posted that.  Here's another method.  Let $u = \sqrt x$, so $x = u^2$ and as $x\to49$ then $u\to 7$.  Then you have:
$$
\lim_{x\to49} \frac{\sqrt x - 7}{x-49} = \lim_{u\to7} \frac{u - 7}{u^2 - 49} = \lim_{u\to7} \frac{u-7}{(u-7)(u+7)} = \cdots.
$$

**IMPORTANT:** The most important reason for learning about limits is to deal with limits of quotients in which the numerator and denominator both approach $0$.  That's because the derivative $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is defined as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}
$$
and the numerator and denominator both approach $0$.